# Monoidal equivalence of categories of modules in different models of higher algebra

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

A result of Shipley states the following (in the language of model categories):

- For a differential graded algebra $A$, the $\infty$-category of (dg)-modules over $A$ agrees with the $\infty$-category of module spectra over the corresponding $E_1$ ring spectrum $HA$.
- For a $H\mathbb Z$-algebra spectrum $B$, the $\infty$-categories of module spectra over $B$ and dg-modules over the corresponding dg-algebra $\Theta B$ are equivalent.

Similar equivalence seems to exist between simplicial modules over a simplicial ring and connective versions of the above rings and modules.

My question is, do these equivalences respect the tensor product of modules over higher rings (here I restrict my attention to ''commutative'' rings over $\mathbb Q$)? I think they should, but I cannot find a reference for this. My reasoning is that the relative tensor product over $A$ is a coequalizer of a diagram $A \otimes M \otimes N \stackrel{\to}{\to} M \otimes N$, and these identifications do respect the absolute tensor product. Is this at least morally correct?

Comment: This follows formally once you know that the equivalence between D(Z) and Mod_{HZ} can be made symmetric monoidal (since algebras, modules, relative tensor products, etc. are all invariant under equivalences of the base sym mon infty cat). A reference is HA.7.1.2.13, but I imagine there is a model categorical precursor

Comment: This is done in the paper of Shipley (HZ-algebra spectra are differential graded algebras). It just wasn't clear to me that these notions are invariant under the base symmetric monoidal infinity category.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I guess what's clear is that if you apply all the $\infty$-categorical constructions to $D(\mathbb{Z})$ or $\mathsf{Mod}_{H\mathbb{Z}}$ then you get equivalent answers. But you were asking if we can keep going back to the model category, doing something, and hoping we get the correct answer on the underlying $\infty$-category. That still works in this case, as you say, because the derived functor of the relative tensor product can be computed by a bar construction which also models the answer given by $\infty$-categorical constructions.